# Concatenate 2d list in python

Tags: python, data-structures, mnist

I'm trying to create a 2d list with shape of [n,784] (the same shape as the MNIST image batches) using multiple [1,784] lists.

`mylist.append(element)` doesn't give me what I'm looking for, where `mylist` is the 2d [n,784] list and element is the [1,784] lists. It would return a list with shape [n,1,784].

I've also tried `mylist[index].append(element)`, and I got a [784] 1d list instead.

Any idea how to solve my problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array(mylist)
newarray = np.concatenate((myarray, element))
```

And if you want to turn it back into a list:

```
newlist = newarray.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

`a = [[1,1],[2,2]]
 b = np.concatenate([a, a], axis=1).tolist()`

The output will be:

`[[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2]]`